# jQuery Change Background After Scrolling Reaches Certain Point

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I am in the process of making a horizontal scrolling site. (DEMO: http://demo.fuelmultimedia.ca). The scooter in the demo is actually a fixed background image.

I need the ability to change the background image to a different scooter once night has been reached (essentially the lights turn on). How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: look for scrollLeft jquery's method.

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     if($(window).scrollLeft() >= 1234){
          $(body).css('background-image','foo.jpg');
      } else {
          $(body).css('background-image','bar.jpg');
      }

});
```

Comment: That code doesn't seem to work for me. I've added the code to the demo.